# Neo4j batch import

Tags: java, neo4j, heap-memory

The neo4j-import tool is very efficient for small graphs, but when I'm trying to import a graph with around 9M nodes and 11M edges, it exceeds the heap size and fails. As far as I know we use *-Xmx* when we run a java class not a java executable like neo4j-import. I appreciate your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**For the `neo4j-import` tool:**

It is actually just a bash file, so you can open it with `vi` or `nano`. You will see something like this:

```
exec "$JAVACMD" $JAVA_OPTS $EXTRA_JVM_ARGUMENTS -classpath "$CLASSPATH" -Dapp.name="neo4j-import" -Dapp.pid="$$" -Dapp.repo="$REPO"
```

So, you can just modify it here or add a little piece of code just above it to set the `$JAVA_OPTS` variable if it's not set yet. For example:

```
# /bin/sh
if [ -z "$JAVA_OPTS" ] ; then
  echo "No JAVA_OPTS set, will use defaults."
  JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128M -Xmx512M"
fi
```

**For the server:**

> JVM configuration goes into the **`conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf`** file

You can read more details [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-jvm.html).

Comment: I'm not using server. I'm just using the executable in bin directory. Increasing the maximum heap size in conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf did'nt help.

Comment: @SiavashSheikhizadeh on which operating system ? Windows/Unix/MacOS ?

Comment: @SiavashSheikhizadeh I guess it's Unix, judging from the filename.

Comment: @bvdb: did you try modifying the `neo4j-import` file, as @Siavash suggested?

Comment: @cybersam ... I think you flipped names ? Because I was the one who suggested it. :)

Comment: Oops. Please flip the names on my previous comment :-).

Comment: I'm working on a Linux server with 256G RAM. I did "export set JAVA_OPT="-Xmx100g", it worked and used around 70G of RAM for a graph with 8.7M/11.8M nodes/edges but for the next one with 9M/12.3M nodes/edges it failed like: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space ....

Comment: Have you tried to also set the `-Xms128M` ? The Xms sets the initial heap size ; the Xmx is a maximum. If you don't set the initial size, then it will perform a lot of resizing at startup, which sometimes causes problems.

Comment: I tried -Xms128M and -Xms1G with -Xmx100G; didn't help. neo4j-import is   just memory-hungry. I doubt it could work on a PC.

Comment: Could be memory hungry, but this is crazy :). I have some more ideas: 2 additional vm properties `-server` improves memory usage, and `XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` could help garbage collection. If that doesn't work, then you could connect using a profiler. To enable access for your profiler, use: `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false`. This way you can watch memory usage remotely, to see what's going on.

Comment: I set these properties:  -Xmx64G -Xms128M -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC , I also used Jprofiler to attach to the process. Almost all the available heap space is allocated to a long[] array which starts to grow rapidly after finishing the "Relationships"  phases which comes after "Nodes", "Calculating dense nodes" phases. Is there anyway to show you what's exactly happening?